# Beautifulsoup does not get all tr in table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with scraping this link http://www.kooora.com/?c=12640&cm=m,
I want to get all  in table#contentTable, but it does not return all of them.
When I inspected the html in browser, I found there is a  tag after the second , and the code read the  till that  tag not after that.

```
#get teams
url='http://www.kooora.com/?c=12640&cm=m'
urlopen=urllib2.urlopen(url)

bso=BeautifulSoup(urlopen.read(),'html5lib')

tcontenttable=bso.find('table',attrs={'id':'contentTable'}).find('tbody')
print len(tcontenttable.find_all('tr')) # only 5
```

It returns only 5, however it is much more than 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is probably that that web-page is not valid HTML (according to https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kooora.com%2F%3Fc%3D12640%26cm%3Dm).

In particular, the validator says:

> Error: End tag `td` seen, but there were open elements.
>
> From line 147, column 5321; to line 147, column 5325

You might be better off using regular expressions to extract known patterns instead of BeautifulSoup in this case.

Comment: I agree with you, but using regex is time consuming, because I have a lot off data to extract it. I tried to change the parser,using "lxml", but does not solve the issue.

Comment: It's no surprise another parser didn't help; they all will have problems with ill-formed input.
That's why I suggested regexes, because you can write more relaxed parsing rules that permit certain types of errors. I don't see why the amount of data you need to extract would keep you from using regexps. Why do you think they are "time consuming"?

Comment: I just found what the problem is, some of the data that I wanted to extract is generate dynamically by JavaScript, that why Beautiful soup does not read all the tr. I think I need to look for module to parse dynamically created tags, I tried Regex, but I got same result.